# Multi-line syntax in to_s with reference to an object

Tags: ruby

I have a problem constructing the to_s method.

```
class Personne
    attr_accessor :prenom, :nom, :email, :telephone, :adresse
    def initialize
        @prenom = @nom = @email = @telephone = ""
        @adresse = Adresse.new
    end
    def to_s
        @prenom + ", " + @nom + "\n" + \
        "Email: " + @email + "\n" + \
        "Tel: " + @telephone + "\n" + \
        @adresse
    end
end
```

The @adresse is and object with very similar to_s method.
The error:

```
in `+': no implicit conversion of Adresse into String (TypeError)
```

I do not understand the issue, since address object has it's own print method.

Comment: but you just call `+` on the object. try to do `@adresse.to_s`

Comment: Yes, thanks, it worked, but I do not understand why I need to ecplicitly call to_s on an objct :/

Comment: Please note that `@prenom = @nom = @email = @telephone = ""` has side effects on mutable string changes: `@email << "me@example.com"` will result in unexpected changes of other instance variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I do not understand the issue, since address object has it's own print
>   method.

You are passing an instance of class `Adresse` as an argument to `+` method, called on string, it throws an error, because it expects an instance of [String](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html) class as an argument.

To make this work you would want to convert it to string using, for instance, `to_s` method.

```
+ @adresse.to_s # would do it for you
```

Comment: Yes, but it should auto triger standard or overwritten to_s, wright?

Comment: @user3685089 no, you have to explicitly cast it to String

Comment: @AndreyDeineko: I think your first sentence ist not true. The OP doesn't call `+` on an instance of `Adresse`. He call `+` on a string with an `Adresse` as an argument.

Comment: @spickermann right, he passes address instance as a argument to it, I'll correct this one!

Comment: I'm sorry guys but I still do not get why I can call "puts adam" (adam is a Personne) and it will auto triger to_s and yet it will not work on adresse?

Answer (score 0):

`some_string + object` doesn't trigger `to_s` on the object. You need to use string interpolation (`"#{some_string}#{object}"`) or need to call `to_s` explizitly (`some_string + object.to_s`):

```
class Personne
  attr_accessor :prenom, :nom, :email, :telephone, :adresse

  def initialize
    @prenom    = ''
    @nom       = '' 
    @email     = ''
    @telephone = ''
    @adresse   = Adresse.new
  end

  def to_s
    "#{prenom}, #{nom}\nEmail: #{email}\nTel: #{telephone}\n#{adresse}"
  end
end
```

Sidenote: `@prenom = @nom = @email = @telephone = ""` sets all attributes to the *same* string. If you did something like `@nom << 'foo'` than `@email` would also change. See this example:

```
foo = bar = ''
foo << 'foo'
#=> "foo"
bar
#=> "foo"
```

Therefore I also changed your `initialize` method.